# Why is this method causing Flash to crash without even being called?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a class called OESDatePicker, as the name suggests it's a date picker.

There's this method in my class that returns a sprite containing week day names:

```
private function DrawWeekDays():Sprite
    {
        var temp:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var wds:Array = new Array();
        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        format.font = "Tahoma";
        format.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
        format.size = 11;
        format.color = 0xffffff;

        trace("HERE");
        /*for( var i:int = 0; i < 7; i++ )
        {
            trace(i);
            wds[i] = new TLFTextField();
            /*wds[i].width = CELL_SIZE;
            wds[i].defaultTextFormat = format;
            if( "en" == lang )
            {
                wds[i].text = day_names_en[i];
            }
            else
            {
                wds[i].text = day_names_fa[i];
            }
            //wds[i].y = 0;*/
            //wds[i].x = MARGIN + i * CELL_SIZE;
            //wds[i].text = "kkk";
            //temp.addChild(wds[i]);
        //}

        return temp;
    }
```

as you can see I have commented out the for loop. If I don't flash will crash upon running the movie. The thing is that not event the trace("HERE") directive gets executed. And the weird thing is that I have never called that method. But if I remove the for loop comments, flash will crash without printing anything in the output. Any ideas????

EDIT: The following code has the same problem too:

```
private function DrawWeekDays():Sprite
    {
        var temp:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var wds:Array = new Array();
        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        format.font = "Tahoma";
        format.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
        format.size = 11;
        format.color = 0xffffff;

        trace("HERE");
        //for( var i:int = 0; i < 7; i++ )
        //{
            //trace(i);
            wds[0] = new TLFTextField();
            wds[0].width = CELL_SIZE;
            wds[0].defaultTextFormat = format;
            if( "en" == lang )
            {
                wds[0].text = day_names_en[0];
            }
            else
            {
                wds[0].text = day_names_fa[0];
            }
            wds[0].y = 0;
            wds[0].x = MARGIN + 0 * CELL_SIZE;

            temp.addChild(wds[0]);
        //}

        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Is an exception/error message being generated and can you share that w/us? Are you using the debug Flash player?

Comment: I removed the loop entirely and tried to implement just one iteration (index = 0), and the problem is still there. So I guess it's got something with wds[i] = new TLFTextField. Might it be that?

Comment: @Sunil: Thanks for answering. No, nothing at all. Not even the trace commands. It just crashes. Like when it's stuck in an infinite loop!

Comment: Oh, and by the way Sunil, YES, I'm using debug flash player :D

Comment: That's odd. It seems to make sense that the trace statements never get output, b/c the function is not being called. This is the point where I would try and clean my project (if I were working in Flash Builder, not sure if Flash CS6 has such an option). You can always try the brute force method of commenting one line at a time to see if that sheds any light on which line is causing the issue. I feel silly for saying this, but a reboot might also be in order :) Or as a test try to use a regular text field instead of TLF, maybe there's some weird mismatch w/libraries or RSLs in your project.

Comment: "I feel silly for saying this" Would it be any mote silly than a function that causes this kinda problem without even being called? :D

Comment: I tried the bruteforce thing, Everything was ok until I reached wds=new TLFTextField(), but the next time I ran flash(CS5) and again commented out that line which I thought was causing the problem the problem was still there!!!!!! I'm gonna explode any second now

Comment: First, check if you are compiling into release mode. In this mode `trace()` functions never provide output. Switch to debug mode, and check if any "HERE" outputs appear. And yes, I'd rather you using a `var ttf:TLFTextField` variable in the loop, and `wds.push(ttf);` after all adjustments.

Comment: Thanks Vesper. No I'm sure i could output trace messages from other parts of the code. It was the first time I used that method of class inclusion, and I guess it will be the last :D, I prefer the importing method. And thanks for the push thing, I didn't know about it :| But now I know :)

Answer (score 0):

What the heck man!!! I was using the class property in Project Properties to use the class. I moved the class to a place where I could import it, and all the problems just faded away!

Thanks for all your help Sunil